# Error message appearing, I don't understand why or how to fix it

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CPT_CHALLENGE1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declaring variable and asking user for input
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Height");
            double Height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            //ensuring that height is up to 101, not including it.
            while (Height < 101)

                //ensuring height is up to 51 but not including 51. with if else loop
                if (Height < 51)
                {
               
                    **(Height + 5);
                    (Height * 1.5);**

                }

        }
    }
}
```

the error messages are : Error  2   Only assignment``, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

and is the same for both of them, thats just error 2, what do I have to fix?

Comment: `(Height + 5);` This is an expression that adds `5` to `Height` but the result is nowhere used and is therefore invalid as a statement. Did you mean `Height += 5;` maybe?

Comment: Error is self explanatory, you need to assign addition to some variable using assignment operator `=`

Comment: @ics3ustudent Did you change it in *both* places?

Comment: After the errors have been fixed, I assume you will want to `Console.WriteLine(Height);` at the end of your Main method?

Comment: Was there a question here originally? Where did it go?

Answer (score 2):

Actually I am seeing two problems here.

The first is that you are using invalid syntax in this section of code :-

```
**(Height + 5);
(Height * 1.5);**
```

What I think you are trying to do is to add 5 to the height and then multiply it by 1.5.

you can easily do that by :

```
Height = Height + 5;
Height = Height * 1.5;
```

or another way you can do so :

```
Height += 5;
Height *= 1.5;
```

Which does exactly the same thing.

---------------------------------------------------------------.

The second problem is with the while loop itself :-

if you look closely at your code you'll see that if the Height is larger than 51 and less than 101 the program is gonna loop endlessly inside that while loop.

I don't know exactly what are you trying to do so can you be more specific about what do you wanna do ? because I actually don't understand your question clearly enough to help you.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do, what are you trying to do with the age ? what is the goal of the while loop and the if statement inside of it ? I need to know that so that I can tell you what are you doing wrong or suggest solutions but I just don't know what are you doing.